# How to use openmp to parallelize the movement of array elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, parallel-processing, openmp

Below code piece is the most time consuming in my program if the pArray is very large. last is the variable for the end position of this array, Idx is the variable for a specific position of the array, so what I want is to move part of the array elements from Idx backward by 1.

```
for(long i = last; i >= Idx; i--)
{
    pArray[i] = pArray[i-1];
}
```

I simply try to use parallel for to parallelize this, but it definitely cannot work. Can anyone tell me whether this code can be parallelized with openmp? And if yes, how to code it? Thanks.

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(long i = last; i >= Idx; i--)
{
    pArray[i] = pArray[i-1];
}
```

Comment: What is pArray? Maybe you can just use `memcpy` (it can be faster than any parallelising)

Comment: What you want to do has a memory dependecies. It wouldn't work as is with openmp but option1: you could try temporary arrays or option2: dividing work load (array) manually such that not more than 1 thread can access a memory location.

Comment: If you have only 1 memory controller, memcpy ought to give good performance.  If you split into blocks, you must deal with the source vs. destination overlap.

Comment: memcpy cannot handle the memory overlap, memmove can do that by using a temporary array, which means the stuffs need to be copied twice, I will have a try to check the performance.

Comment: memcopy can handle it by automatically reversing the loop to deal with the overlap.  You are right that memcpy will probably skip that step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue you have is that your code has loop-carried dependencies, i.e. there is a dependency between iterations.

So your code is:

```
for(long i = last; i >= Idx; i--)
{
  pArray[i] = pArray[i-1];
}
```

Now, let's say `last = 4` and `Idx=1`. You would have something like:

```
  iteration 0: pArray[4] = pArray[3];
  iteration 1: pArray[3] = pArray[2];
  iteration 2: pArray[2] = pArray[1];
  iteration 3: pArray[1] = pArray[0];
```

If you parallelize this with four threads (let's say statically) and thread 0 is assigned iteration 0, thread 1 with iteration 1, and so on, you would have incorrect results depending on which thread executes first. If thread 0 executes *before* thread 1, thread 0 would use the old value for `pArray[3]`, whereas if thread 0 executes *after* thread 1, thread 0 would use the new value for `pArray[3]`, calculated by thread 1.

Since your iterations are not independent, the loop cannot be parallelized straightforward.

Since apparently all you want is to move the values of your array one position forward, I think a better approach would be to use pointer arithmetic or reorganize your loop and other pieces of your code to try to either eliminate the dependency or the loop entirely.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to do `memmove` in parallel.  Here is an example that does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define N 20

int main() {  
    int x[N+1];
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) x[i] = i+1;
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) printf("%d ", x[i]); puts("");
    #pragma omp parallel
    {
        int ithread = omp_get_thread_num(), nthreads = omp_get_num_threads();
        size_t pos = ithread*N/nthreads;
        size_t n = (ithread+1)*N/nthreads - pos - 1;
        int tmp = x[pos+n];
        memmove(&x[pos+1], &x[pos], sizeof *x*n);
        #pragma omp barrier
        x[pos+n+1] = tmp;   
    }
    for(int i=0; i<N+1; i++) printf("%d ", x[i]); puts("");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the array in multiple blocks.
So each thread will work only on his block.

For instance if your array is of size 1000, and you have 4 threads, then the first thread will move values in the block 1-198, the second in block 201-398 and so on.
Don't forget the special case of moving value on the border (200 to 199 for instance)

You don't need to create a 'parallel for' only a 'parallel' area will be useful.

Comment: You need in this case a `parallel for` (if the dependencies were not there). If you use just a `parallel`, each thread in the region will execute _all_ the iterations of the loop instead of the iterations being distributed among threads.

Comment: I basically implemented what you said in words (although I did it before reading your answer in detail).